# Disabling and Customizing Browser Default Context Menu on right click in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular

I've successfully disabled the browser's default context menu using the contextmenu event in my Angular app by creating a directive. However, I'm now looking to take it a step further and customize the menu options based on my application's requirements.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU6cx.png)

Here's the code for the directive that currently disables the context menu:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDisableContextMenu]'
})
export class DisableContextMenuDirective {

  @HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])
  onContextMenu(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

Now, I want to know how I can modify this directive or add additional functionality to selectively hide or disable specific context menu options in my web app. What changes should I make to achieve this level of customization?

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please highlight the problem you are facing with implementation, please share code for a minimal reproducible example, a stackblitz would be great for debugging!

Comment: Are you looking for some like this [link](https://netbasal.com/context-menus-made-easy-with-angular-cdk-963797e679fc) -create a custom context menu?-

Comment: No, I don't want to create a custom context menu, I want to hide or disable the options of the browser's default context menu.
like I want to remove/hide/disable the "Open link in new tab" option of the context menu.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: You cannot do that. Either create a custom context menu, or use the existing one.